# Find Inverse Laplace of $\frac{e^{-2s}}{(s^{3})}$ and evaluate it $f(3)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse, step-function

I was able to solve it by using second shift theorem which led my answer to be $y(t)=u(t-4)-(t-4)^2/2$ but how would I evaluate it for $f(3)$?

I am unsure on what to do with u.

I tried to use unit step function but I am still unclear on how to solve it.

The answer is supposed to be a numerical value but u in the equation is throwing me off.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y(3) = u(-1) - (1/2)(-1)^2 = 0 - 1/2 = - \frac{1}{2}$

Edit, it seems like the real solution (as someone posted earlier was t-2 instead of t-4).

Therefore, the solution is:
$y(3) = u(1) - (1/2)(1)^2 = 1 - 1/2 = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: How is u(-1)=0?

Comment: The Heaviside step function is defined as 0 when t < 0 and 1 when t >= 0.

Comment: Isn’t t 3 by f(t) which would make it 1 instead of 0? Or is it t negative 1 by evaluating 3-4 inside u(t-c)?

Comment: u(-1) = 0 and u(1) = 1 so u(t-3) = u(3-2) = u(1) = 1

Answer (score 1):

I get $\frac {e^{-2s}}{s^3} = \int_2^{\infty} \frac 12(t-2)^2e^{-st}\ dt$

$f(t) = \mathcal L^{-1}\{\frac {e^{-2s}}{s^3}\} = \frac 12u(t-2)(t-2)^2$

$f(3) = \frac 12$